# Compare two javascript string dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I compare the following two dates?

```
var start_date = $('#start_date').text();
var end_date = $('#end_date').text();
alert(start_date + ' ' + end_date); // '2013-01-01 2013-01-02'

# how to do the following?
if (start_date > end_date) {...}
```

Comment: convert those strings to native JS `Date` objects. right now they're strings, and will be compared using string rules.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: If you know they are always year-month-day then string comparison is fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to compare two string dates in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781153/how-to-compare-two-string-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If this is always in this format (`yyyy-mm-dd/2013-01-01`) then you can compare as string

```
var d1 = '2013-11-01', d2 = '2013-11-02';
console.log(d1 < d2); // true
//console.log(d1.getFullYear()); won't work, not date object
```

[See Lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

> An important exploitation of lexicographical ordering is expressed in
>   the ISO 8601 date formatting scheme, which expresses a date as
>   YYYY-MM-DD. This date ordering lends itself to straightforward
>   computerized sorting of dates such that the sorting algorithm does not
>   need to treat the numeric parts of the date string any differently
>   from a string of non-numeric characters, and the dates will be sorted
>   into chronological order. Note, however, that for this to work, there
>   must always be four digits for the year, two for the month, and two
>   for the day

But, you can use this to compare dates

```
var d1 = new Date("11-01-2013");
var d2 = new Date("11-04-2013");
console.log(d1);
console.log(d1.getMonth()); // 10 (0-11)
console.log(d1.getFullYear()); // 2013
console.log(d1.getDate()); // 1
console.log(d1 < d2); // true
```

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EHeSj/4/).

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
var d1 = Date.parse("2013-11-01");
var d2 = Date.parse("2013-11-04");
if (d1 < d2)
```

Also check out **[Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)** and **[Compare dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)**

Answer (score 1):

Try using a timestamp.

```
var date1 = +new Date("2013-11-01");
var date2 = +new Date("2013-11-04");

console.log(date1);
console.log(date2);

console.log(date1>date2);
```