# Comparing dates with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare dates and apply a class based on the result.

```html
<div class="" id="date" title = <%... %> />
```

The title is the date and time returned from a query (IE. `Mar 23, 2016 05:00 AM`). I would like to check if the DATE is less than today (ie `Mar 23, 2016`).  I am sure this will require a function, but was hoping there may be a shortcut I am missing.  Any help is appreciated.  Not very proficient in jQuery yet.

EDIT:

Maybe I am going about this wrong.  As stated this is a resultset from a query that is in a nested repeater.  If the date returned is less than the current date (time is of no consequence) then I want to add a class to the given label.  this will be repeated for each returned result.  Should I look at doing this via Java script post databinding or code-behind (C#)?  Just getting back into programming after several years of DBA work.  Thanks again in advance

Comment: Perhaps you mean Javascript rather than jQuery? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: Note that date comparison is pure Javascript; no jQuery involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.parse()` to compare those string dates to see if one is greater than the other. See [This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781153/how-to-compare-two-string-dates-in-javascript) about the same topic and [This MDN article on Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function isPrevious(date, compareWith){
    var check_date = new Date(date);
    var today_date = new Date(compareWith);

    return check_date.getTime() < today_date.getTime();
}
```

Test

```
console.log(isPrevious('Mar 22, 2016 05:00 AM', 'Mar 23, 2016 05:00 AM'));
console.log(isPrevious('Mar 22, 2016 05:00 PM', 'Mar 22, 2016 00:01 PM'));
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/obcam1vc/