# Compare dates as strings in typescript

Tags: javascript, date, typescript

I am trying to compare two dates as strings in typescript. The input I have is as below :-

```
startWindow = '05/2014'
endWindow = '05/2018'
```

I need to write a function to check if the start Window is greater than the end Window.

Both the inputs are of string type.

Thanks

Comment: You keep getting downvotes because you asked people to write your code for you, rather than assist you in fixing the code that you've already written.  The site is meant to help people who can't find the answers, not to do outsourced work for you.

Comment: A string is not a proper way to work with dates. I suggest you to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14781232/943082 (by Garry).

First you should do the comparison, and then show the dates in the format that you want to display. Hope that it helps.

Comment: my bad guys... will take the advice into account when i post questions in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it to a date and then compare them:

```js
function convertDate(d)
{
 var parts = d.split('/');
 return new Date(parts[1], parts[0]);
}

var start = convertDate('05/2014');
var end = convertDate('05/2018');


alert(start < end);
```

Comment: not like that always work, my issue is i cant convert the date i have to Date, as it's beyond the range of valid date

Comment: Can you give an example of the date you are trying to parse?