# How do I compare two dates in different formats using typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, date, format

My token expire time `value(currentUser.expire)` is '2018-08-01T17:29:17+01:00'

I want to compare the current time.

```
currentUser.expire > new Date().valueOf()
```

`new Date().valueOf()` is '1533110765293'

The format of the two values is different.

What is the most appropriate method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338463/how-do-i-do-a-date-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575235/compare-dates-as-strings-in-typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (new Date('2018-08-01T17:29:17+01:00') > new Date()) {
    // do something
}
```