# How does Javascript string compare work with dates?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

So I was looking into doing date comparison with strings in javascript and I found tons of stack overflow posts saying that you cannot do it.

Reference:

[how to compare two string dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781153/how-to-compare-two-string-dates-in-javascript)

[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

However this following [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdOQwm?editors=1111) works exactly as you would expect with nothing but strings, it even works when one of them is YYYY-MM-DD and the other is YYYY/MM/DD. Can anyone explain why this works and why virtually everyone on stack overflow and other sites recommend you make date objects? Seems like a lot of overhead

```
var bigger = "2017-01-01";
var smaller = "2000/01/01";
var biggest = "2018-01-01"
if (bigger > smaller ){
  console.log("logical!");
}

if (smaller > bigger ){
  console.log("illogical!");
}

if (bigger > biggest ){
  console.log("illogical!");
}

if (biggest > smaller ){
  console.log("logical!");
}
```

Comment: Caution with your assumption on different separators: `"2000/01/01" > "2000-01-13"` gives `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are always compared character by character.

```js
var bigger = "2017-01-01";
var smaller = "2000/01/01";

console.log(`'${bigger}' > '${smaller}'`, bigger > smaller);

bigger = "2000-12-01";
console.log(`'${bigger}' > '${smaller}'`, bigger > smaller);
```

When we compare this `"2000-12-01"` to this `"2000/01/01"` it seems as though it fails. But the comparison matches the first four characters `'2000'` and then compares the fifth `"/"` and `"-"` and the `"-"` has a lower ASCII value then `"/"` does.

A string comparison has to check each character, one by one, until it finds a difference. If no difference it ever found then the strings are the same.

Once a difference is found that indicates which string is greater then the other.

#### Example:

String 1: `"My dog howels"`

String 2: `"My dog barks"`

The code checks each character until it finds a difference:

`Position 0: "M" vs "M"` - Same

`Position 1: "y" vs "y"` - Same

`Position 2: " " vs " "` - Same

`Position 3: "d" vs "d"` - Same

`Position 4: "o" vs "o"` - Same

`Position 5: "g" vs "g"` - Same

`Position 6: " " vs " "` - Same

`Position 7: "h" vs "b"` - `"h"` is greater than `"b"`.

So string 1 is greater then string 2.

---

### Compare with Date Object

If you want to compare dates then it is best practice to use the date object:

```js
var bigger = Date.parse("2017-01-01");
var smaller = Date.parse("2000/01/01");

console.log(`'${bigger}' > '${smaller}'`, bigger > smaller);

bigger = Date.parse("2000-12-01");
console.log(`'${bigger}' > '${smaller}'`, bigger > smaller);
```

`Date.parse()` will convert your properly formatted date string into a date object and then compare the integer representation of the dates, giving accurate results.

The `Date` object stores all dates as a number and numbers are must faster to compare.

---

### Compare without Date Object

If You don't want to use a date object then you need to get rid of the separators to compare just the numbers. But this may not work if your date objects are not always two digits for month and day.

```js
function fixDate(dateStr) {
  return dateStr.replace(/[\/\-\s]/g, '');
}

var bigger = fixDate("2017-01-01");
var smaller = fixDate("2000/01/01");

console.log(`'${bigger}' > '${smaller}'`, bigger > smaller);

bigger = fixDate("2000-12-01");
console.log(`'${bigger}' > '${smaller}'`, bigger > smaller);
```

The `replace` with the regular expression removes all `'-'`, `'/'` and white space from your string.

So `'2018/01/11'` becomes `'20180111'` and `'2000-05-01'` becomes `'20000501'`.

> Both methods only work if your date strings are properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

When JavaScript compares two strings, it compares them lexicographically. So it works in some cases, but generally it is a bad idea to use it for dates.