# Ordering datetime asc/desc

Tags: jquery

I have a table of dates

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01/03/2018 02:31 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01/13/2018 03:00 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>09/02/2017 02:31 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>11/29/2017 09:30 PM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03/01/2018 03:00 AM</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

that I want to order chronologically. I found another thread that recommended using:

```
$('th').click(function(){
    var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()))
    this.asc = !this.asc
    if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
})
function comparer(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB)
    }
}
function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html() }
```

but output doesn't order newest to oldest correctly.

I get this:

```
Date
01/03/2018 02:31 AM
01/13/2018 03:00 AM
03/01/2018 03:00 AM
09/02/2017 02:31 AM
11/29/2017 09:30 PM
```

when it should start with the newest date first. And advice on how I can get these sorted correctly?

Comment: you need to define your own comparer to compare two date string. check this [compare two date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781153/how-to-compare-two-string-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the cell values have to be parsed into date format. And later on you need to reformat it to Locale String `toLocaleString` so that you can use `localeCompare` function.

First change:

```
var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
```

to:

```
var valA = Date.parse(getCellValue(a, index)).toLocaleString(), valB = Date.parse(getCellValue(b, index)).toLocaleString();
```

And here is the working version:

```js
$('th').click(function(){
    var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()))

    this.asc = !this.asc
    if (this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
})
function comparer(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = Date.parse(getCellValue(a, index)).toLocaleString(), valB = Date.parse(getCellValue(b, index)).toLocaleString();
        //console.log(valA, valB, "____", valA.localeCompare(valB),"_____",valA>valB);
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB)
    }
}
function getCellValue(row, index){
    return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html();
}
```

```css
th {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: lightgrey;
}
td, th {
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01/03/2018 02:31 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01/13/2018 03:00 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>09/02/2017 02:31 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>11/29/2017 09:30 PM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03/01/2018 03:00 AM</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this works.

> **EDİT:** For this to be sorted DESC, as you stated, you also need to change one more line:

Change this:

```
if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
```

to this:

```
if (this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
```